# Suggestions for Epson WF-1110 WiFi printer?

Tags: wireless, drivers, lubuntu, printing

I'm running Lubuntu-14.10-desktop-i386, and the printer install went seamlessly - system-config-printer found my printer on the network and recommended a driver. Unfortunately, that driver, and another I tried, result in a stream of blank pages instead of a test page. There is no specific WF-1110 driver in the current distro; the Epson WorkForce 1100 driver doesn't work (you'd think it would) and the recommended driver Epson WF-7018 Series - CUPS+Gutenprint v5.2.10 does the same blank-pages thing.

I'm not totally sure it's a driver issue (you'd think the WF-1100 driver would do the trick), so I'm wondering if there are other tweaks I should try.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this, and figure others may benefit. Turns out you can download ([from here](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule)) the generic Epson Linux driver package, called: `epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.4.4-1lsb3.2_i386.deb` (for my case, a 32-bit Ubuntu distro).

You have to install `lsb`, then this Debian package.

```
sudo apt-get install lsb
cd Downloads                       # or wherever the file you downloaded is
sudo dpkg -i epson-inkjet*.deb
```

After that, the `system-config-printer` tool finds the driver and you're all set.

Comment: Here's the page where you can find the download: http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule

Comment: Well, this isn't all that great. The printer works, but it prints very very light, and I can't find a way to darken it (including setting saturation to max with the advanced options under Lubuntu). If anyone has a tip on this little detail, I'd appreciate it! (It's essentially unusable with the lightness of printing that happens as a "default dot matrix printer", as I think this driver operates.)